# how to make array of 15000 jbuttons in swing java jframe and set action against each row with button?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtable

i am developing an application in java swing using jframes jtable and pagging etc, 
i have 15000 records in my database now i want to add print button against each row in last column of jtable so i can set action of that row with button column.
kindly help me how to make array of 15000 jbuttons and add it to jtable column in swing jawa jframe so i can add action of each row by clicking on that button ?

i tried this code using button renderer and button editor class

```
class ButtonRenderer extends JButton implements TableCellRenderer
{

    public ButtonRenderer() {
        // set button properties
        setOpaque(true);
    }


    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object obj, 
            boolean selected, boolean focused, int row, int col) {

//        setText((obj==null) ? "":obj.toString());
        if(selected)
        {
            setForeground(table.getSelectionForeground());
            setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
        }
        else
        {
             setForeground(table.getForeground());
             setBackground(UIManager.getColor("Button.background"));
        }
        setText((obj==null) ? "" :obj.toString());

        return this;
    }

}

class ButtonEditor extends DefaultCellEditor
{
    protected JButton button;
    private String label;
    private boolean isPushed;

    public ButtonEditor(JTextField txt) {
        super(txt);
        button = new JButton();
        button.setOpaque(true);

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                fireEditingStopped();
             //   throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            }
        });
    }
    // override a couple of methods

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object obj,
            boolean selected, int row, int col) {
        // set text to button, set clicked to true, then return the btn object
        if (selected) 
        {
            button.setForeground(table.getSelectionForeground());
            button.setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
        } 
        else 
        {
            button.setForeground(table.getForeground());
            button.setBackground(table.getBackground());
        }   
        label=(obj==null) ? "" :obj.toString();
        button.setText(label);
        isPushed = true;
        return button;
    }
    // if button cell value changes, if clicked that is

    @Override
    public Object getCellEditorValue() {
            DisplayRecords dis = new DisplayRecords();        
        if(isPushed)

        {
            String query = "Select * from Voters";
            int row = table.getSelectedRow();
            String table_click = (table.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0).toString());
            String query = "Select * from Voters where ID='"+table_click+"' ";
            Connection connection = getConnection();
            Statement st;

            try 
            {
                st = connection.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
                while (rs.next())
            {
               String r1 = rs.getString(1);
               dis.id.setText(r1);
               dis.id.setEditable(false);
               String r2 = rs.getString(2);
               dis.t2.setText(r2);
               dis.t2.setEditable(false);
               String r3 = rs.getString(3);
               dis.t3.setText(r3);
               dis.t3.setEditable(false);
               String r4 = rs.getString(4);
               dis.t4.setText(r4);
               dis.t4.setEditable(false);
               String r5 = rs.getString(5);
               dis.t5.setText(r5);
               dis.t5.setEditable(false);
               String r6 = rs.getString(6);
               dis.t6.setText(r6);
               dis.t6.setEditable(false);
               String r7 = rs.getString(7);
               dis.t7.setText(r7);
               dis.t7.setEditable(false);
               String r8 = rs.getString(8);
               dis.t8.setText(r8);
               dis.t8.setEditable(false);
               String r9 = rs.getString(9);
               dis.t9.setText(r9);
               dis.t9.setEditable(false);
               String r10 = rs.getString(10);
               dis.t10.setText(r10);
               dis.t10.setEditable(false);
               String r11 = rs.getString(11);
               dis.t11.setText(r11);
               dis.t11.setEditable(false);
               String r12 = rs.getString(12);
               dis.t12.setText(r12);
               dis.t12.setEditable(false);
               String r13 = rs.getString(13);
               dis.t13.setText(r13);
               dis.t13.setEditable(false);
               String r14 = rs.getString(14);
               dis.t14.setText(r14);
               dis.t14.setEditable(false);
               String r15 = rs.getString(15);
               dis.t15.setText(r15);
               dis.t15.setEditable(false);
               String r16 = rs.getString(16);
               dis.t16.setText(r16);
               dis.t16.setEditable(false);
               String r17 = rs.getString(17);
               dis.t17.setText(r17);
               dis.t17.setEditable(false);
               String r18 = rs.getString(18);
               dis.t18.setText(r18);
               dis.t18.setEditable(false);
               String r19 = rs.getString(19);
               dis.t19.setText(r19);
               dis.t19.setEditable(false);
               String r20 = rs.getString(20);
               dis.t20.setText(r20);
               dis.t20.setEditable(false);
            }
            } 
            catch (SQLException ex) 
            {
                System.out.println("Print Button Click exception");
            }
            dis.setVisible(true);
            dis.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
//            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(button, label+"Clicked");
        }
        // set it to false now that its clicked
        isPushed = false;
        return new String(label); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public boolean stopCellEditing() {
        //set clicked to false
        isPushed = false;
        return super.stopCellEditing(); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    protected void fireEditingStopped() {

        super.fireEditingStopped(); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
}
```

but i am not able to set action of button against each row

Comment: Why add a button to each row? Why not just one button and when you click that button, just print those rows selected in the Table? In addition, you are really going to render all the 15k rows in one page? I suggest put them into different pages.

Comment: i put them in 100 records per page but now i want to add print button to print records of that row...

Comment: normally that kind of layout is used in web ui. If used in Swing, it could imply significant performance degradation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but now i want to add print button to print records of that row...

So what is wrong with the suggestion given by BOND?

But if you really want a separate button on every row of the table you can use the renderer/editor found in [Table Button Column](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/). It allows you to render a button in a column and associate an Action with that button.